# How to get response from "ping -c 1 example.com"?

Tags: perl

In BASH can I ping a server like so

```
for i in $MY_SERVER_LIST; do
   if ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      # $i is alive
   fi
done
```

and I would like to do the same in Perl, but how do I get the response from

```
my $response = `ping -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1`
```

**Question**

How do I do the same in Perl, but without using any packages like `Net::Ping`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are interested in the exitcode of `ping` not the output; forget about the `$response` and examine the exitcode in `$?`.

Comment: Very interesting. So exitcode `512` means not pingable, and `0` means pingable.

Comment: That's probably implementation-specific.  If the manpage for `ping` says that, or you have access to the code, or you have tested it, then yes, but those values will differ between implementations.  However what will certainly be consistent is that `0` means 'good'.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting, all the bash is testing for is a 0 return. So it makes no difference what the error code is--in the example you provided. I'd say if you definitely want to know the error, don't pipe the error to /dev/null.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting : If you want the exit (return) code as the shell would report it, you need to bit-shift the return code: $? >> 8. Hence the apparent return code of 512 is really 512 >> 8 or 2. See [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, it's almost certainly exiting 2, not 512. When dealing with exit codes you should be bitshifting them right 8 bits; i.e. `my $exit = $? >> 8`. Edit: F***, beaten.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Net::Ping !

```
use Net::Ping;
$p = Net::Ping->new();
print "$host is alive.\n" if $p->ping($host);
$p->close();
$p = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
$p->bind($my_addr); # Specify source interface of pings
foreach $host (@host_array)
{
print "$host is ";
print "NOT " unless $p->ping($host, 2);
print "reachable.\n";
sleep(1);
}
$p->close();
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html